# How to change wrap for hidden elements of datepicker jquery-ui

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Datepicker crate hidden element (with id attribute "ui-datepicker-div") in body tag.
How set my wrapper for datepicker hidden element?

**Js code:**

```
window.("#datepicker").datepicker({ ??? });
```

See example:
[official site](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').wrap('<div class="datepicker-wrapper"/>');
```

Whole script would look like (based on your [example page](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html)):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').wrap('<div class="datepicker-wrapper"/>');
    });
</script>
```